# MongoDB - Get a single element from an aggregation query

Tags: database, mongodb

I am using the following aggregation query:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "profiles",        
            localField: "user",
            foreignField: "user",
            as: "userDetails"
        }
    }
])
```

It returns a result that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1523b98d9dd16d832a8c5e"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5d1504e29dc0bd55461adca7"),
    "recipeName" : "Pizza",
    "ingredients" : "Flour and sauce",
    "userDetails" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1505089dc0bd55461adca8"),
            "user" : ObjectId("5d1504e29dc0bd55461adca7"),
            "handle" : "jack",
            "status" : "Developer"
        }
    ]
}
```

This includes the entire "profile" as a key called "userDetails".
However, I don't want all that information. I only need the user's handle.
I want the result to look *exactly* like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1523b98d9dd16d832a8c5e"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5d1504e29dc0bd55461adca7"),
    "recipeName" : "Pizza",
    "ingredients" : "Flour and sauce",
    "handle" : "jack"
}
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Use $project -- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Answer (score 0):

**if You need  result run this query,**

```
 db.posts.aggregate(
     [{ 
       $lookup:{
             from:'profiles',
             localField:'user',
             foreignField:'user',
             as :'userDetails'
         } 
      }, 
     {
     '$unwind':'$userDetails'
      },
      { 
       $addFields:
              {
              'handle':'$userDetails.handle'
              }
       } ,
        {
          $project:
           {
           '_id':1,
           'user':1,
           'recipeName':1,
           'ingredients':1, 
           'handle':1
           }}])`
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without specifically naming fields from db.posts?  I think additional fields may be added in the future, and it would be easier if there was a way to just include all of them without naming them in the projection.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can try this query:

```
 db.posts.aggregate([{$lookup: {from: "profiles",        
                localField: "user",foreignField: "user",as: "userDetails"
            }},{'$unwind':'$userDetails'},
        {$project:{ '_id':1, 'user':1, 'recipeName':1, 'ingredients':1, 'handle':'$userDetails.handle'}}]);
```